# Add jsfiddle as a resource url in a separate jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have a `jsfiddle` url where I wrote some Util or helper function which is reused in processing of data in various examples.

For example: I can write some division code in fiddle 1 which is also my Util function:

```
function divide(a, b, callback) {

    var quot = Math.floor(a / b),
        rem = a % b;

    callback(quot, rem);

}
```

And I was trying to use this url as a resource in a different jsfiddle url in which I might have called the `divide` function which didn't work. I know we can use cdn libraries in resource but I wanted to know if using of 1 fiddle url and access its function in a different url is possible or not. If it is then How can I achieve it.

Comment: Afaik this is not possible. Maybe you can add a request to [the jsfiddle roadmap](https://trello.com/b/LakLkQBW/jsfiddle-roadmap) ... And lo and behold, it is already an excepted [request](https://trello.com/c/j4bwwWdV/10-include-other-fiddles-via-require-or-import)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just raised it on Github: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1697